# Glimpse WebAPI Support

Tags: c#, .net, glimpse

Does Glimpse (the diagnostics plugin for .NET) support diagnostic information from ASP.NET Web API? I installed it and ran against the website, it captures ASP.NET MVC requests and returns information about them but I don't see any Web API request information.

http://getglimpse.com/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no official support for ASP.NET Web API yet for Glimpse, but there is a feature request on the GitHub page for the project; although this is 4 months old and the comment says they were working on support for MVC4, which came out last week. I would guess it might be available soon, but who knows.

[Glimpse GitHub Project Page - Issue 282 - Request for support of ASP.NET Web API](https://github.com/Glimpse/Glimpse/issues/282)

Comment: We have now finished MVC4 support and the next framework we take on will be WebAPI. Its a big framework and will take a bit of work. Please feel free to go to the referenced issue and comment what you would like to see.

Comment: @anthonyv - Awesome, I have taken a look at Glimpse quickly and I really like it. Also saw on Twitter the Heads-Up Display was recently released, very much looking forward to trying that out. Great work!

Comment: That link isn't really a request for Glimpse to work with WebAPI, so much as bug that it doesn't work with WebAPI *help pages*.  It appears, however, that some work is being done for WebAPI https://github.com/Glimpse/Glimpse/pull/736 and http://blog.getglimpse.com/2014/03/11/glimpse-1-8-4-released/

Answer (score 0):

The issue Mark pointed to was actually a bug where Glimpse interfered with WebApi's help pages, and the links EBarr pointed out were for [a bug that interferes with Web API Descriptors](https://github.com/Glimpse/Glimpse/issues/365).

There was some actual work being done to get Web API support, but the [pull request](https://github.com/Glimpse/Glimpse/pull/749) was never completed and the [issue](https://github.com/Glimpse/Glimpse/issues/715) was closed in June of 2016, to be included on a [huge list](https://github.com/Glimpse/Glimpse/issues/226) of "improvement ideas". [This blog post](https://blog.markvincze.com/use-glimpse-with-asp-net-web-api/) claims to at least get basic stuff like trace logging from web api requests, but I was unable to get it working with the latest version of Glimpse. I'm suspecting the fix for the issue EBarr mentioned might actually make Glimpse ignore non-MVC requests.